# How to edit output of "tail"?

Tags: php, bash, shell

I am trying to create a web progress bar for `MakeMKV`.

```
run # tail -f /disc_progress
```

I get a result as a file:

```
PRGV: 0,0,65536 <= 0% (65536 goal = 100%)
from 0%
PRGV: 716,0,65536
,
PRGV: 13281,13281,65536
,
PRGV: 65042,65041,65536
until 100%
PRGV: 65536,65536,65536 <= 100%
```

`65536` in the end are `100%`, so I can start something.
Ideally, I would like to pay the penultimate,
for example in `PRGV: 65042,65041,65536`

```
Var1 = 65042 and Var2 = 65041
```

How do I cut off at the beginning "PRGV:"?
How do I cut `65041,65536` at the end, that would be for me important variable 0%
and the number in the middle (between the commas (65041)).

that should then be in the php variable:

```
echo $Disc_Progress=shell_exec("sudo tail -f / disc_progress");
```

Link to the [GitHub FFmpegUI.](https://github.com/Sub-7/FFmpegUI)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and/or use "guided mode" to ask questions.

Comment: You can't use `tail -f` in `shell_exec()` since it never exits, and `shell_exec()` doesn't return until the command completes.

Comment: Where does `This is for a new Linux server, shell, php` come from in that output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for that:

```
$get_progress_value=shell_exec("tail -1  /disc_progress");
$Progress_Array=preg_split('/:|,/',$get_progress_value);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($Progress_Array);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => PRGV
    [1] => 120 
    [2] => 536
    [3] => 65536
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output of `tail -f` to a command that copies its input to its output until it gets to the `100%` line, and then exits.

```
$Disc_Progress=shell_exec("sudo tail -f /disc_progress | sed '/100%/q'");
```

The line you want will be the second to last line in `$Disc_Progress`.